# No secret_key is set with a runtime error but im pretty sure that I set the secret key correctly

Tags: python, json, mongodb, flask

Hi I am getting this error in my code even though I am pretty sure that I set my secret key correctly

```
# Laptop Service
from bson import json_util
import json
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask import Flask

from flask_wtf import FlaskForm, csrf
from wtforms import StringField,PasswordField,BooleanField,validators

from passlib.apps import custom_app_context as pwd_context

from itsdangerous import (TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer \
                                    as Serializer, BadSignature, \
                                    SignatureExpired)
from flask_login import (LoginManager, current_user, login_required,
                            login_user,logout_user,UserMixin, confirm_login,
                            fresh_login_required)

import os
import flask
from flask import request, Response,redirect,url_for,render_template
import arrow  # Replacement for datetime, based on moment.js
import acp_times  # Brevet time calculations
import config
from datetime import datetime as datetime
import dateutil.parser
import time
from pymongo import MongoClient
import logging
logging.basicConfig(foramt='%(levelname)s:%(message)2',
                    level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
app = Flask(__name__)
CONFIG = config.configuration()
app.secret_key = CONFIG.SECRET_KEY
the_csrf = csrf.CSRFProtect(app)
the_csrf.init_app(app)

client = MongoClient('mongodb://mongodb:27017/')


# Instantiate the app
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
```

This is my header for the file and I use a credentials file to set my secret key.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are creating your *app* **twice**.

So, in your second *app* the ***app.secret_key* does not exist**, because it is a new Flasp *app* object.